# Cytoscape Collapse all parent nodes by default

Tags: reactjs, cytoscape.js

I am using cytoscape.js with react-cytoscape and cytoscape-undo-redo and cytoscape-expand-collapse. I am also using COSEBilkent layout for my graph(as I need to have option of compound nodes). At first I receive all nodes and expanded groups. I would like to have these compounded nodes to be collapsed at first, but I can not find a solution. Can anyone please help?
[image: What i Have right now]

[image: What I expect to be at first render]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out finally api.collapseAll() does the trick